# Django: How to make form conditional?

Tags: python, django, forms, validation, conditional-statements

I have a form with two fields. The user should be required to only select one of the two. Not both and not none.
I tried solving this by overwriting the clean method as described in the Django Doc:

forms.py

```
class ConfigureWorkout(forms.Form):
    first_exercise = forms.ModelChoiceField(empty_label="select", label="Choose First Exercise", queryset=FirstExercise.objects.all(), required=False) 
    sec_exercise = forms.ModelChoiceField(empty_label="select", label="Choose Sec Exercise", queryset=SecExercise.objects.all(), required=False)

    def clean(self):
        first_exercise = self.cleaned_data.get("first_exercise")
        sec_exercise = self.cleaned_data.get("sec_exercise")

        if first_exercise and sec_exercise:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Enter either a First Exercise or a Secondary Exercise.")
        else:
            return self.cleaned_data
```

views.py

```
def configure(request):
    configure_workout = ConfigureWorkout()

    if request.method == "GET":
        return render(request, "userprofile/some.html", configure_workout)

    else:
        return render(request, "app/other.html")
```

template

```
<form action="{% url 'configure' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ configure_workout }}
    <input type="submit" name="configuration_completed">
</form>
```

However, if I test this by selecting both fields in the form, there won't be an error displayed/raised. I pass the form successfully and get sent to "other.html".

What am I missing?
Thanks so much in advance for any help :)

Comment: Could you check if the returned cleaned data (`first_exercise`,  `sec_exercise`) inside the clean function has the value you would expect from the query?  And what data type does this data have

Comment: Furthermore, when overriding the `Form.clean()` method the documentation  [(Cleaning and validating fields that depend on each other)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other) states that `super().clean()` should be called.

Comment: I tried doing it exactly as the documentation described (or so I hope), even with the ' `super().clean()` method. Behaviour doesnt change.

Not quite sure how I can check the returned cleaned data? Calling `print(configure_workout.clean())` in the views.py throws an `AttributeError: 'ConfigureWorkout' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you're not passing actual data to your form. Maybe this will help:

```
def configure(request):
    configure_workout = ConfigureWorkout()

    if request.method == "GET":
        return render(request, "userprofile/some.html", configure_workout)

    else:
        configure_workout = ConfigureWorkout(request.POST)
        configure_workout.is_valid()
        configure_workout.clean()
        return render(request, "app/other.html")
```

Comment: This yields an AttributeError: "'ConfigureWorkout' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'", which traces back to first_exercise = self.cleaned_data.get("first_exercise")

Comment: @Alex cleaned_data is set after you call `is_valid()` method

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much. Adding `is_valid()` before `clean.()` solved the issue. I am now able to catch the ValidationError and display an error message in the template.

Answer (score 0):

Building on @trafalinos answer and looking at the documentation on [Forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other), I would suggest doing the following:

In `forms.py`:

```py
class ConfigureWorkout(forms.Form):
    first_exercise = forms.ModelChoiceField(empty_label="select", label="Choose First Exercise", queryset=FirstExercise.objects.all(), required=False) 
    sec_exercise = forms.ModelChoiceField(empty_label="select", label="Choose Sec Exercise", queryset=SecExercise.objects.all(), required=False)

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()  # compare documentation
        first_exercise = cleaned_data.get("first_exercise")
        sec_exercise = cleaned_data.get("sec_exercise")

        if first_exercise and sec_exercise:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Enter either a First Exercise or a Secondary Exercise.")
        else:
            return self.cleaned_data
```

And (credits to trafalino) in `views.py`:

```py
def configure(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        configure_workout = ConfigureWorkout()
        return render(request, "userprofile/some.html", configure_workout)

    else:
        configure_workout = ConfigureWorkout(request.POST)
        configure_workout.clean()
        return render(request, "app/other.html")
```